# WCF 4 REST - Acquiring the underlying response stream object for writing

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, c#-4.0

**Background:** I am currently using the Visual Studio 2010 online template "WCF REST Service Template 40(CS)" and it works great for my primarily JSON based service. I've even got it working to return a stream when returning an image.

**Scenario:** I am currently looking into the server push & multipart/x-mixed-replace technology to replace the polling for images method I am currently using.

**The Problem:** The issue I am facing is that I am unable to find a way to get the underlying response stream for a REST request, I know the the template is trying to help by abstracting this away from me, but in order to implement the multipart/x-mixed-replace mechanism properly i will need to write directly to this stream and have full control of what i write to the client.

Any help would be much appreciated. The server push tech seems so cool!

Answer (score 0):

I have returned all sorts of things in the response, including documents, spreadsheets etc. It looks something like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public class MyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate="{id}")]
    public Stream GetDocuments(int id)
    {
       WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = GetContentType();
       Stream result = CreateTemporaryStream();
       /* Write your data in the correct format */
       return result; 
    }  
}
```

You can pretty much return any format you wish. The client obviously have to be able to parse the stream and extract the individual streams from the response.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Werner, this is actually the method I'm using to return images as well. Although what I'm really asking is how to write to the response stream WITHOUT having to first return from the function to send the response, which is what is needed to implement multipart/x-mixed-replace messages. Thanks!

Comment: I misunderstood how "multipart/x-mixed-replace" is used. You may be better off writing an HttpModule to handle these types of requests.